# Test that a function doesn't create a log entry

Tags: python, logging, python-unittest

I want to test that a function doesn't create a log entry.

```
with self.assertLogs() as logs:
    function_that_logs_nothing()
```

But this fails because `assertLogs()` checks for log entries. If no logs are done it raise an exception. Makes sense.

Is there something like `assertNotLogs()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertNoLogs) a `assertNoLogs()` exists.